# Hiding Azure CDN url

Tags: asp.net-core, angular5, azure-cdn

Is there any way to hide the Azure CDN Url in the browser. We have developed the application using ASP.Net Core 2 with Angular 5, also is there any helper class for archiving this (**Microsoft Recommended**)

Answer (score 0):

In these kind of scenario, hiding is not a valid option, instead i would recommend you to implement the encryption/decryption logic.

Here is something which you can do:

- Populate the Azure CDN url by posting the data from backend.
- Before posting the data to your front end , encrypt the url and send it
- While you will send the request to CDN , at the back end, decrypt the URL.

This is the elegant solution int his scenario.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't want *azureedge.net*? [Use a CNAME DNS entry pointing to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain) - you can even [use it with HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl?tabs=option-1-default-enable-https-with-a-cdn-managed-certificate).

It'll be possible to determine that you're using Azure's CDN, but it won't be so visible in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom DNS  this will mask the CDN URL

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain?tabs=azure-dns%2Cazure-portal%2Cazure-portal-cleanup